# Eloquent : Order query result by number of null values

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a working query like that :

```
$users = User::whereNotNull('name')orWhereNotNull('phone')orWhereNotNull(email)->get()
```

My database datas look like that

```
id | name | phone | email
1  | Luc  | null  | null
2  | Bob  | null  | bob@g.com
3  | null | null  | null
4  | Bil  | +2121 | bil@g.com
```

With my precious query it will return lines with id : 1, 2 and 3. But I want to order them by number of columns with null, which mean the users with the most null datas. In my example it will return in this order : 3, 1, 2

Is it possible to do it with eloquent? Like with a `withCount()` and `orderBy()` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this :

```php
$users = User::whereNotNull('name')
           ->orWhereNotNull('phone')
           ->orWhereNotNull('email')
           ->orderByRaw('ISNULL(name) + ISNULL(phone) + ISNULL(email) DESC')
           ->get();
```